# How to get the sizes of the text blocks?

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts

I need to add a few text strings above an image one below the other. I can not make this with one block, because icons added to each line (not in the code example). But since each string has a different length, there is either a large interval between blocks or they close each other.
How can I calculate rectangle size base on font sizes and string length?

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w,h);
Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

Color color = colors[0];
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
textSize = grp.MeasureString(text[0], font);
System.Drawing.StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    grp.DrawString(text[i], font, brush, new RectangleF(60, h + i*step, (int)(w*0.5)-50, step), stringFormat);
}
```

Comment: You already seem to have found MeasureString; but why don't you use the `textSize` returned? You also can skip the initialization in the line above since a) SizeF is a struct and thus always initialized and b) you overwrite it with the assignment in the line below.

Answer (score 0):

[`Graphics.MeasureString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx) can calculate - quite precisely - the space, expressed as a rectangular area, that a string of Text requires when drawn in a defined device context with specified font characteristics and size constraints.

Your current constraints are:
- The Surface (canvas) Size, defined by a Bitmap dimensions.
- The initial margins (left, top)

> You didn't say whether the text should wrap when wider than the
>   imposed canvas width.
> Here, I'm assuming that it does.

Each Font has it's own metrics. `.MeasureString()` takes care of those measures for us. However, some parameters should be specified to define the behaviour and the overall quality of the rendering.

The [`Graphics.TextRenderingHint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs(v=vs.110).aspx) property is useful to specify the quality of the text.
See `TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` and `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit` and their differences. The latter represents the highest quality possible. Nonetheless, it's results may fail the expectations in some contexts. When drawing on a transparent surface, for example.

In the current context, I'm using `TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit`. In my opinion, it's rendering is visually better in this case. It would be different if you were printing on paper.

[`StringFormat()` Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) are used to alter the way the Text disposition  effects its measure.
Here, `StringFormatFlags.LineLimit` (1) and `StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces` (2) are used to verify (1) that the vertical measure is correct (otherwise, the last line of a wrapped string would be clipped) and to see whether the presence of trailing spaces (2) cause unexpected word wrapping.
If word wrapping is not desidered, use the `StringFormatFlags.NoWrap` flag.

---

> Note that, in the following code, the Text drawing position is defined
>   by:

```
PointF(LeftMargin, TextVerticalPosition)
```

> The Text Block (Rectangle) size is defined by:

```
RectangleF(TextPosition, TextSize)
```

> This measure can be used to draw other objects near the starting
>   point of a line of text.

```
string[] TextLines = new string[] { "First Line of Text", 
                                    "Secon Line of Text a bit larger than the one before", 
                                    "Third Line of Text, this is mid-sized." };

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(280, 200))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        Font font = new Font("Calibri", 22, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        graphics.Clear(Color.Goldenrod);
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        graphics.TextContrast = 10;
        StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | 
                                                     StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces);
        stringformat.Trimming = StringTrimming.Word;

        float LineSpacing = 10.0F;
        float LeftMargin = 30F;
        float TextVerticalPosition = 10F;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            SizeF TextSize = graphics.MeasureString(TextLines[i], font, (bitmap.Width - (int)LeftMargin), stringformat);
            PointF TextPosition = new PointF(LeftMargin, TextVerticalPosition);
            graphics.DrawString(TextLines[i], 
                                font, 
                                new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                                new RectangleF(TextPosition, TextSize), 
                                StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            TextVerticalPosition += TextSize.Height + LineSpacing;
        }
        graphics.Save();
        font.Dispose();
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```

This is the visual result:

[image]